# Custom event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that there is a lot of questions like mine, but I don't think it's a duplicate.

I want to create my own custom event, for exemple onresize or onshake.

And I would like to make a library, then the user of my library would just write that :

```
<script src="theLib.js" ></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener("shake",myFunc,false);
</script>
```

I saw a lot of tutoriels and questions on stackoverflow but either they are using jQuery(I want the most simple exemple to make a custom event) or the user must not just write `window.addEventListener`.

Can you please explain me the most basic way to add a custom event?

Comment: Curiosity or a real need? Why don't you want to use jQuery?

Comment: There's a great MDN article about just that (`document.createEvent`) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firing and capturing custom events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057223/firing-and-capturing-custom-events)

Comment: (related) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827716/emulate-clicking-a-link-with-javascript-that-works-with-ie

Comment: Is document.createEvent cross browser?

Comment: Event handling is a common source of cross-compatibility pain. I would prefer to do something less integrated with the underlying browser if I were you.

Comment: particularly, is document.createEvent working on safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer finally :

```
//Library part
var evt=document.createEvent("Event");
evt.initEvent("foo",true,true);
function blah()
{
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
window.addEventListener("load",blah,false);

//User part
window.addEventListener("foo",function(){alert("Hi");},false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to trigger the event somehow. This answer gives particularly good depth: [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

You'll probably have to use `document` instead of `window`, though.

Comment: From what I understand, by sing the `initEvent` method you create an event which can be fired on any element--the document, the window, a text field, whatever. So you simply use `addEventListener` on any object which gets that event fired.

Comment: And where do I write the tests (for exemple, testing if the iphone is shaked or not)

Comment: Anywhere in the document. Doesn't matter where. The trouble is figuring out when the phone is shaken, but it seems like you've taken care of that.

Comment: then, I write `function dataavailable(){/*Tests*/}` then the code of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript, then `window.addEventListener("dataavailable",otherFunc,false);` ???????