# Jquery `on` event handler: event delegation and passing custom data

Tags: jquery

I have a form that gets loaded through an ajax call, which means I need to use `event delegation` in order to detect when a select box in the form gets clicked.

My code looks like the following snippet below:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "form select", selectFunction );
```

However, in addition to utilizing `event delegation`, I'd also like to be able to pass custom `event.data` to the `on` handler function.

So, I'd *like* to have my code snippet look like below...

```
$( document ).on( "click", "form select", { foo: 'bar' }, selectFunction );
```

...and my handler function would act like something like this.

```
function selectFunction( event ) {
    console.log(event.data.foo); // outputs 'bar'
}
```

Unfortunately, `event.data` returns `undefined`.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/67Ec5/ (well, `click` didn't work, so I used `focus`). So if it doesn't work, then your are not passing the right value as data argument (or none at all).

Comment: why not do something like this: $( document ).on( "click", "form select", selectFunction({ foo: 'bar' });

Comment: @kasperTaeymans: And how would `selectFunction` look like then?

Comment: `click` works here: http://jsfiddle.net/649Nd/ (just click within the red area)

Comment: function selectFunction( event, data ){alert(data.foo)} If this is not an option you need to create a custom event. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057223/firing-and-capturing-custom-events

Comment: @kasperTaeymans: That wouldn't work. You are calling `selectFunction` immediately, so the object you pass in would be accessible via the `event` variable, not `data`. Then you are passing the *return value* of that function call to `.on`, which is `undefined`. If you wanted it to work like in your first comment, then the function would have to look like `function selectFunction(data) { return function(event) { ... }; }`. In any case, there is nothing obvious wrong with the OP's code, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: yes must be function(event){selectFunction({foo:"bar"})};

Comment: @kasper, I tried your first suggestion and Chrome's console will spit out the following error at me: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'`.

Comment: @acdcjunior Yours answer (and the one that I wanted) worked for me. It's weird because in my `selectFunction`, `console.log event` will show `null` in its data field. However, `console.log event.data` will show the object literal `{ foo: 'bar' }`. I suspect it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of javascript, but I don't know what exactly yet.

Comment: And thank you everybody for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hum. Weird indeed. Try `console.dir(event)` some other time, maybe it will show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2mMbT/6/

This works -

```
$(document).on("click","#form-select", {foo: "bar"},SubmitForm);

function SubmitForm(event)
{ 
   alert(event.data.foo); 
}
```

I think the issue is in the selector you are using - "Form select" or something else entirely.

Comment: This works for me. It's weird because in the `handler function`, `console.log event` will show null in its data field. However, `console.log event.data` will show the object literal `{ foo: 'bar' }`. I suspect it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of javascript. However, I don't know exactly why this occurs.