# Namespace for click event solution with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, namespaces, addeventlistener, custom-event

How to write this jQuery code

```
$(selector).on('click.custom-namespace', function () {...});
```

into vanilla JavaScript solution?
addEventListener don't get events with custom namespace.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event Handler Namespace in Vanilla JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817397/event-handler-namespace-in-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript click event listener on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)

Comment: This takes some additional setup in vanilla JS to do. There are small libraries that help with this sort of thing: For example: [event-bundle](https://github.com/kevinokerlund/event-bundle)

Comment: Trigger/fire of custom event might also help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057223/firing-and-capturing-custom-events

Comment: @Hitmands thanks, I have already read this thread and I also try custom Event class that Andrew mention. But this has one problem and it is if I declare same event name with same namespace to two or more different elements. Other answer was irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I don't see any event namespace in that thread. Creating custom events looks great, but I don't know how I can apply something like this click.custom-namespace using this custom event.