# resend event to page

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent

I am working on a big project and it is required to resend event to page.

Let me explain :

A box `<div>` is over an image `<img>` like this :

```
 <div>
   <div id="box"></div>
   <img>
 </div>
```

Once user clicks on the `box`, it moves to another location, but the image must be clicked in same time, these two elements must be clicked in same time. ( it is long to explain why )

Maybe it is possible to resend the event to the same location, or maybe is it possible to create another event at the current mouse position..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('selectorA').on('eventType', function(e){
    $('selectorB').trigger(e); // the SAME event
});
```

And without jQuery:

```
element.onSomeEvent = function(e){
   otherElement.dispatchEvent(e); // the SAME event
};
```

[DOCs on `dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)

Comment: I think IE8 vs. every other browser requires different syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/a/827793/724626

Answer (score 1):

Why not call the `click` method on the image?

```
function OnclickOfBox()
{
    document.getElementById('imageID').click();
}
```

If you need to catch and pass the `event` parameter, that can be done fairly simply.