# (After a click event) how to open a list of links in new tabs with a delay after each opening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a script (for Greasemonkey) that (while visiting a specific page),
if you click the link that I insert into the page
*(the link "does nothing", i.e. I use `event.preventDefault();`)*
to open all links in page in new tabs,
**but with a delay between each tab opening**, eg. 500 ms.

I have this code (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22011929))

```js
var z = ($('table td').find('a'));         // selection via jQuery
$("#mylink").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    for (i=0; i<z.length; i++) {    
        window.open(z[i].href, '_blank');    
    }
});
```

The above works, but opens all links simultaneously.

So, I have tried enclosing the `window.open` line into either:

```js
setInterval(function() {        
        window.open(z[i].href, '_blank');   
}, 500);
```

or:

```js
setInterval("window.open('"+z[i].href+"','_blank')", 500);
```

but didn't help:
both did nothing, and I only get continuous `TypeError: z[i] is undefined` errors in Browser Console when I click the link.

---

For what it's worth, if the fact that it's a link is what's causing the problem,
I have also the code for creating a button, instead of a link:

```
var z = ($('table td').find('a'));         // selection via jQuery

var button = document.createElement("button");
button.id = 'mybutton';
button.type = "button";
button.value = "im a button";
context.appendChild(button);    

$("#mybutton").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    for (i=0; i<z.length; i++) {            
        window.open(z[i].href, '_blank');
    }
});
```

Changing the `window.open` line in either of the two ways described above doesn't help,
and I get the same errors in Browser Console.

Comment: `setInterval("window.open(z[i].href, '_blank')", 500);` fyi, you gave a string instead of a function for the 1st parameter.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I had this answer on my mind. So, I corrected it into `setInterval("window.open('"+z[i].href+"','_blank')", 500);` but it just waits 0.5 sec and then fires all URLs simultaneously (even if using `setTimeout`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are using jQuery. Why not take full advantage of it? Instead of using a `for` loop, you could just use the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method of jQuery. Also, instead of `setInterval()`, you should use `setTimeout()` for this use case. The following works for me.

```
var z = ($('table td').find('a'));         // selection via jQuery
$("#mylink").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    var interval = 0;   //set the starting point for the timeout interval

    z.each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        setTimeout(function() {
            window.open(href, '_blank');
        }, interval);

        interval += 1500;   //up the interval to ensure a delay between opening

    });
});
```

Side note, I hope the user is expecting this functionality, as this can be annoying. Also, most modern browsers are going to block these popups. Just my two cents.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I wanted. Thank you!